# Filtering a NSMutableArray and returning only numbers

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray called **myMutableArray** inside him, I have the following values:

```
('R$ 118.98','AE 12.00 er','R$ 456.99')
```

What I would do, is find a way to filter the information contained within this array, thus making it returns only numeric characters, for example:

```
('118.98','12.00','456.99')
```

I have a simple code who get the lines inside an array:

```
for(int x=0; x<[myMutableArray count]; x++){

myMutableArray[x];//We need to find a way to filter and update this informations to only store numbers.

}
```

What the code I can put in my code to filter the information inside my array to only storing numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
//create a new mutable array to store the modified values
NSMutableArray *arrFinal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//fast-enumerate within myMutableArray
for (NSString *strCurrent in myMutableArray) {
    NSString *strModified = [strCurrent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];

    [arrFinal addObject:strModified];
}

NSLog(@"%@",[arrFinal description]);
```